# QScriptEngine with negative numbers, pe: 5*-2

Tags: qt, qregexp

I'm trying to run a script which evaluates only expressions that have add, subs, mults and divs, but can use negative numbers. This negative numbers are taken from instructions like this:

```
set 1, 5 * D[5]
```

This implies that you have to store the result of `5 * [whatever it's in a variable]`. If this variable contains a negative number, let's say `-2`, the expression will be `5*-2`, and this expression is evaluated by QScriptEngine, resulting 0 (Error). I need to parse expressions like this to be `5*(-2)`. In PERL, a RegExp to do it will be:

```
$expresion =~ s/\[\\*\\+\\-\\/](\\-\d+)/($1)/g;
```

How can I do this in Qt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
QString s = "...";
s.replace(QRegExp("[\\*\\+\\-\\/](\\-\\d+)"), "\\1");
```

See http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qstring.html#replace-16